jxls/jexl/apache POI excel template: insert an extra total row for rows of same id
I'm exporting this from ReportServer, it goes SQL->Excel Template, and I use jxls to style and format. And JXLS relies on JEXL scripting syntax, which I am not familiar with.
Now, I have rows like below, and I want to add a total row after each name/id, totaling the number of credits a person took across all terms. I'm totally perplexed on what to do.



id
name
term
credits




1
taz
2010
7


1
taz
2011
6


1
taz
2012
11


2
bob
2022
30


2
bob
2022
26



My goal is this:



id
name
term
credits




1
taz
2010
7


-

2011
6


-

2012
11


-
taz Total

24


2
bob
2022
30


-
-
2022
26


-
bob Total

56





<table style="width: 50%; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 20px 0; font-size: 18px; text-align: left;">
    <tr>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px; background-color: #f2f2f2;">id</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px; background-color: #f2f2f2;">name</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px; background-color: #f2f2f2;">term</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px; background-color: #f2f2f2;">credits</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">1</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">taz</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">2010</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">2011</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">2012</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #ffff99;">
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">taz Total</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">2</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">bob</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">2022</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">2022</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #ffff99;">
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">bob Total</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">56</td>
    </tr>
</table>



I am using the JX comment markup inside of excel comments and cells. My code right now is about as simple as it gets.
On my 1st sheet that puts the raw data (it's called 'Dynamic list'):
A1=ID, A1.Comment=jx:area(lastCell="C2")
A2=${row.ID}, A2.Comment=jx:each(items="data" var="row" lastCell="C2")
..

On my second sheet that formats the data:
A1=ID,
 A1.Comment=jx:area(lastCell="C2")
A2.formula=IF(COUNTIF('Dynamic list'!$A$2:A2, 'Dynamic list'!A2) > 1, "",  'Dynamic list'!A2),
 A2.Comment=jx:each (items="data" var="row" lastCell="C2")
..

